# Removing indention before first table column

Tags: tables, indentation

I want to remove the space *before* the first column entry of a table environment in a CV, in order to align it with the section header.

The output looks as follows:[image]

I am aware that it might look somewhat crowded without the indentation but I need this extra space :)

The code so far is at follows:

```
\documentclass{resumeGerman}

\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor={linkcolour},
urlcolor={linkcolour},
}

\name{John Doe} 

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\cdot$}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL DETAILS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Personal Details}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Adress & Silk Road 123 \\
& 12345 Silk City \\
Date of Birth & 01.01.1900 \\
Place of Birth & Silk City\\
Phone & (123) 1234 5678  \\
Email & \href{mailto:john.doe@silkmail.com}{john.doe@silkmail.com}
\end{tabular}
\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Education}

\begin{tabular}{>{\em}rp{13cm}}
Expected 08/2016 & \textbf{Silk City University} \\
& M. Sc. in Silk Science\\
& {\parbox{0.73\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Specialization in Silk Fabriques
\item Overall GPA: 5.678 
\end{itemize} }} 
\end{tabular} \medskip \\

\begin{tabular}{>{\em}rp{13cm}}
09/2011 -- 02/2015 & \textbf{Silk City University} \\
& B. Sc. in Silk Business \\
& {\parbox{0.73\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Relevant Coursework: Silk Industry (GPA 4.0/4.0), CRM in Silk Business (3.7), International Silk Trade (4.0)
\item Bachelor Thesis: {\em Are the times of the silk road really over?} (4.0)
\item Overall GPA: 3.7
\end{itemize} }} 
\end{tabular} \medskip \\

\begin{tabular}{>{\em}rp{13cm}}
08/2013 -- 12/2013 & \textbf {Silk Road University, India} \\
& Semester Abroad \\
& {\parbox{0.73\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Relevant Coursework: Logistics (4.0), Silk Engineering (4.0)
\item Overall GPA: 3.65 
\end{itemize} }} 
\end{tabular} \medskip \\

\begin{tabular}{>{\em}rp{13cm}}
08/1999 -- 06/2008 & \textbf{Silk City School} \\
& {\parbox{0.73\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Degree: High School Diploma
\item Overall GPA: 3.3/4.0
\end{itemize} }} 
\end{tabular} \medskip \\
\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Work Experience}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

P.S. Not sure how I could provide the .cls file for "resumeGerman" here, so let me know how to do it if you guys need it. It might be possible without the file, if focusing only on the indentation. :)

Comment: You have several tabular headers like `\begin{tabular}{>{\em}rp{13cm}}`. Insert `@{}` before `>{\em}` to achieve your objective. I'm afraid I can't demonstrate directly that this'll works since I don't have access to your document class.

Comment: The minimal working example you provided is not working. :)

Comment: and possibly `\noindent` before the tabular (impossible to tell from the fragment) why have you specified `p{13cm}` for a fixed parbox of width 23cm when the only thing inside it is `\parbox{0.73\textwidth}` ?

Comment: Thanks Mico, for your quick response.
However, the first tabular (Personal Details) includes this feature and yet is not aligned with "Personal Detail's" P... 
Also adding it to the first tabular for Eduaction, this does only marginally shift the word "Expected" to the left...

It might be due to the style file. Which can be found here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv

Comment: @Mico Your comment solved the issue. You should post that as an answer!

Comment: @Alenanno - Done. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions; I'm afraid I can't verify that they'll work since I don't have access to your document class.

- Insert the instruction `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` in the preamble.
- Modify the four instances of the tabular header line

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{>{\em}rp{13cm}}
  ```

  so that they read

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\em}rp{13cm}@{}}
  ```

  i.e., insert `@{}` at the beginning and end. This'll set the amount of whitespace that's inserted at the left-hand and right-hand edges of the `tabular` environment to zero.

Comment: Ah, I had only edited them to be `\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\em}rp{13cm}}` without doing the rest and it worked. :P